# azure-eventhub import breaks Azure function

Tags: python, windows, azure, azure-functions

### Issue

I am deploying a python azure function as a zip package to a linux function app.
If my code contains an import of the `azure-eventhub` package, the function does not run after deployment, even though the `azure-eventhub` package is included in the `requirements.txt`.
It does run locally without any issues though.
It also runs just fine in the function app if the import is removed.

### Reproduce

Create a zip file `function_app.zip` containing the following files:
`function_app.py` :

```py
import logging
import azure.functions as func

app = func.FunctionApp()

@app.function_name(name="source")
@app.schedule(
    arg_name="timer",
    schedule="*/10 * * * * *",
    run_on_startup=True,
    use_monitor=False
)
def source(timer: func.TimerRequest) -> None:
    logging.info("Source executed!")
```

`requirements.txt` :

```
azure-functions
azure-eventhub
```

`host.json` :

```json
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    }
  },
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[3.15.0, 4.0.0)"
  }
}
```

Create Azure function app from Azure CLI:

```
$prefix = "yourprefix"
az login
az group create --name "$prefix-rg" --location "East US"
az storage account create --name "${prefix}storage" --location "East US" --resource-group "$prefix-rg" --sku "Standard_LRS"
az functionapp create --name "$prefix-function-app" --storage-account "${prefix}storage" --consumption-plan-location "eastus" --resource-group "$prefix-rg" --functions-version 4 --os-type "Linux" --runtime "python"
```

Deploy the zip file to the function app:

```
az functionapp deployment source config-zip -g "$prefix-rg" -n "$prefix-function-app" --src .\function_app.zip
```

The code is now deployed to the function app and the `source` function is executed every ten seconds, as you can confirm by having a look at the log stream. However, when you add the

```py
from azure.eventhub import EventData
from azure.eventhub.aio import EventHubProducerClient
```

imports to the `function_app.py` file in the zip file and redeploy the function with

```
az functionapp deployment source config-zip -g "$prefix-rg" -n "$prefix-function-app" --src .\function_app.zip
```

, it will not be executed anymore.

(Run `az group delete --name "$prefix-rg"` to clean up the resources.)

### Logs

Log Stream of the function app after deployment:

```
Connected!
2023-03-23T13:31:59Z   [Information]   Loading functions metadata
2023-03-23T13:31:59Z   [Information]   Reading functions metadata
2023-03-23T13:31:59Z   [Information]   1 functions found
2023-03-23T13:31:59Z   [Information]   0 functions loaded
2023-03-23T13:31:59Z   [Information]   Loading functions metadata
2023-03-23T13:31:59Z   [Information]   Reading functions metadata
2023-03-23T13:31:59Z   [Information]   1 functions found
2023-03-23T13:31:59Z   [Information]   0 functions loaded
2023-03-23T13:33:52Z   [Information]   Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '00000000000000000000000009A7A025'.
2023-03-23T13:35:46Z   [Information]   Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '00000000000000000000000060EAB21B'.
2023-03-23T13:46:14Z   [Verbose]   Received request to drain the host
2023-03-23T13:46:14Z   [Information]   DrainMode mode enabled
2023-03-23T13:46:14Z   [Information]   Calling StopAsync on the registered listeners
2023-03-23T13:46:14Z   [Information]   Call to StopAsync complete, registered listeners are now stopped
```

### Run the function locally

If you want to confirm that the function runs locally with the imports, follow these steps:

run

```
python -m venv .venv
.venv\scripts\activate
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Then run:

```
func init
```

Start the [azurite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azurite?tabs=npm) storage emulator in a seperate process.
You can install azurite with `npm install -g azurite`. Run azurite with

```
azurite
```

You can now run the function.
run:

```
func start
```

It will run every ten seconds, even with the imports.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [MSDoc](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/azure-functions/recover-python-functions.md), the multiple Python workers setting is not currently supported in the v2 programming model. Enabling intelligent concurrency by setting `FUNCTIONS WORKER PROCESS COUNT` to greater than (>1) 1 is not supported for functions developed using the v2 model.

I would suggest you try setting the `FUNCTIONS_WORKER_PROCESS_COUNT` to 1 in your `host.json` file.

If still the issue persists, Use `event-hub` package in a separate module and import it in the function as detailed in the above document.

**Note**: And uninstall the event-hub package and reinstall it with the latest version (5.11.2).

```py
pip install azure-eventhub
```

After checking the above one's, I tried the same requirement as yours in my environment and was deployed as well as executed successfully.

init.py:

```py
import  logging
import  azure.functions  as  func
from  azure.eventhub  import  EventData
from  azure.eventhub.aio  import  EventHubProducerClient
app = func.FunctionApp()
@app.function_name(name="")
@app.schedule(
arg_name="",
schedule="*/5 * * * * *",
run_on_startup=True,
use_monitor=False
)
def  source(timer: func.TimerRequest) -> None:
logging.info("")
```

***Updated code:***

`host.json`:

```bash
{  "version": "2.0",
  "extensions": {
    "eventhubs": {
    }
  },
  "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_PROCESS_COUNT": <number_of_worker_processes>
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you please share your `host.json` file?
And could you please elaborate on why you think it has got something to do with the `FUNCTIONS_WORKER_PROCESS_COUNT` app setting? Because I don't think I modified it anywhere and `1` is already the default value.

Comment: Yes you are right. Default value is "1". But `Python` is a single-threaded runtime and a host instance for Python can process only one function call at a time. So, giving `FUNCTIONS_WORKER_PROCESS_COUNT` increases the workers count and make the functions running asynchronously as detailed in [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/python-scale-performance-reference). @gummersbach

Comment: Thank you. Could you please share your `host.json` file with me? You mentioned 
"setting the FUNCTIONS_WORKER_PROCESS_COUNT to 1 in your host.json file."
in your answer. I would be curious to see how you did that

Comment: @gummersbach I updated in the above answer. You can add in that way. Ypu can also refer [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-hubs?tabs=in-process%2Cextensionv5&pivots=programming-language-python).